# Error NullPointerException java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, integer

Estoy haciendo una clase que convierte numeros pasandole el numero y la base

```
private String resultado;

private ArrayList<Integer> numeros;

public String convertir_a_base(Integer base, Integer numero) {
    numeros.add(numero);
    while(numeros.get(numeros.size()-1)!=0) {
        resultado = resultado + ((numeros.get(numeros.size()-1))%base);
        numeros.add(numeros.get(numeros.size()-1)/base);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

He probado a hacerlo escribiendo directamente los numeros en el codigo y funciona bien... Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu propiedad `private ArrayList<Integer> numeros;` tiene que ser inicializada.
De lo contrario, `numeros.add(numero);` dará `NullPointerException`, al ejecutar `add` sobre `numeros`, que vale `null`.

En resumen, cambia `private ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();`

Por otro lado, declara números como List, no ArrayList. Declara interfaces, instancia clases.

`private List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado!